# How to pass list of encoded checkboxes through state param in msal react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, msal-react, msal

Im using @azure/msal-browser component with my reactjs app.

Here is the example code that it works (it redirects me to microsoft oauth), and everything works ok.
Now, I'm trying to pass some list of checked/unchecked checkboxes from initial page, to set after login is successful.

Currently I'm trying with a simple string "Hello World" to pass through state.

My page looks like this:

```
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

const App = () => {
    const msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: 'some-guid',
            redirectUri: 'https://localhost:3001/'
        }
    };
    const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    msalInstance.initialize();
    const doLogin = (msalInstance) => {
        const loginRequest = {
            scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
            state: 'Hello World'
        };

        try {
            const accounts = msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
            if (accounts.length === 0) {
                const result = msalInstance.loginRedirect(loginRequest).then((loginResponse) => {
                    if (loginResponse) {
                        console.log(loginResponse.accountState);
                    }
                });
                msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise().then((test1) => {
                    console.log(test1);
                });
                console.log(result);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Login Error:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <button
            onClick={() => {
                doLogin(msalInstance);
            }}
        >
            Login
        </button>
    );
};
```

After login, I have following generated redirect uri with params:

- code
- client_info
- state

url looks like this (simplified url, remove extra chars from encoded props):

https://localhost:3001/#code=M.C107_BL2.2-d9a8362a22&client_info=eyJ2ZXI2NmRhZCJ9&state=eyJpZCI6ImM0OGU1NWZlLWY1YjQtNDJhNS1hYTAwLWIzYzAzMTE5N2M5MCIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoicmVkaXJlY3QifX0%3d%7cHello%World

Is there any function inside msal component which **encode** this string? Or I need to do it manually?

**Preferebale result:**

Instead of simple string `"Hello World"` I would like to have a list of checkboxes like keypair values:

`[{id:1, checked: true},{id:22, checked: false},{id:100, checked: true}] => this should be encoded`
on return url, again decoded from the url and set up checkboxes by id.

Thanks